# Support to Read only one data_gram message/packet in each BIO_read() for DTLS

Tags: ssl, openssl, tls1.2, dtls

I'm new to DTLS and trying to implement a DTLS server application using a third party library.

The BIO_read() function which we are using attempts to read as many bytes as requested and doesn’t return one datagram message per read.

For example :
ret = BIO_read(ssl, buffer, 2048);
Here it tries to read the available data upto 2048 bytes and doesn't work per packet basis.

Currently the problem is we don't have any data/field in the application data to calculate the packet size received. So it will be difficult for us to split the messages at application layer if read() returns a DTLS record which contains multiple packets.

Do we have any option which can be set on BIO object/Connection handle which force BIO_read() to return only one message/packet at a time in any standard libraries like openssl, etc.. ?

So that We will ask our library team to provide same kind of support to us?

Thanks.

Comment: What kind of BIO are you using? As long as you are using the dgram BIO it should respect the packet boundaries.

Comment: Hi Matt, The library which we are using provides API called BIO_new() to create a BIO object for both TLS and DTLS support. And from their sample applications , I see they set TCP/UDP socket to BIO object using api bio_set_socket(BIO, socket) to differentiate BIO object for TLS and DTLS applications

Comment: And the library doesn't provide api like BIO_new_dgram() to create a BIO object specific to datagram appliactions.

Comment: Does this mean, In any library BIO_read() should behave based on the BIO type which we are passing? 
i.e if we pass datagram BIO to BIO_read() then it should respect the packet boundaries and should return only one packet at a time to the application layer?

Comment: It is up  to the type of BIO to understand the underlying transport layer. If you are using DTLS then you will need a BIO that understands and preserves packet boundaries. OpenSSL's dgram BIO (created via the `BIO_new_dgram()` function) does this and will automatically preserve those boundaries. It also does all sorts of other things such as query the underlying transport MTU size and communicate this back up to libssl so that libssl doesn't create overly fragmented handshake packets. You can use other BIOs with DTLS, but if so those BIOs should at the very least ensure that they respect...

Comment: ...packet boundaries. They *should* also support other features such as MTU querying - although libssl will work without it. From what you said above it sounds like you are using some kind of custom BIO provided by some other library (not OpenSSL)? Is that correct. If so you should check with the authors of that library why the BIO does not appear to be respecting the packet boundaries.

Comment: Thanks @MattCaswell for the detailed explanation. Yes I'm not using openssl and requested the library team to provide support for datagram BIO for DTLS.